# WordPress and Google Indexing

Tags: seo, google, wordpress, search-engine-indexing, ranking

One of my domains i am working on, the site is using wordpress and literally a barebone site. A couple of sample pages not even an SEO plugin or site map generated as yet, why? - Well i setup the WordPress site on the domain on Christmas Eve and was not going to be doing any work on it christmas day/boxing day, and i was sure it would not get indexed within 2 Days with, as i mentioned just a barebone site. However this morning i put in site:"URL" in google and it has already indexed it, which is great in one way but i am worried as its just a barebone site with some sample pages, thus if it gets searched it shows up just the sample data and how long will it take for google to recrawl the site, which i hope to complete within the coming week. I am worried that once i finish the site in a week , have the robots.txt and site map all done, it will still show the useless sample pages that were only for temp use....HELP! :/

- Submit the site to google to recrawl once its complete, and use 301 Redirects to the homepage, for the 404 dummy pages that will be overwritten by real content? or will 301 Redirects to the homepage hurt the domains Ranking or Auth?

Any suggestion's much appreciated?

Cheers and Happy holidays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install a quick ["Coming Soon"](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/coming-soon) plugin. This page will serve as a better placeholder than a barebone skeleton. You should also publish a [sitemap.xml](http://www.sitemaps.org/) file so that Google knows that empty pages that were already indexed should be discarded. By the time your site kicks in you will hopefully have a fresh start without the barebone reminiscences.